# Git: reflect local repo changes in the two private remote (GitHub) repos

Tags: git, github, workflow

I have a local git repo where I make all development for a project. I have two **private remote (!)** GitHub repos: the first is on my personal account, the second on the account of my client whom I do the project development for.

I push from the local repo to both remotes daily. My issue is that I have to manually switch between first and second GitHub account credentials to push to the desired one.

I.e. I am on Windows. I have set up the first remote credentials on Windows Credentials Manager. I pushed to the first remote all day. I need to push everything to the second remote at the end of the day. I remove first remote credentials in the manager. I add the second remote credentials. I push to the second remote. I change credentials back to the first remote ones. Doing all this is very annoying.

Is there a solution to assign the credentials to each remote once and then just `git push all` or something?

Or is there the other git workflow (mirroring or what?) that would allow to keep both private remotes up to date to my local one?

Comment: Can you generate an SSH key and add it to both accounts? https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks but GitHub does not allow to add the same key to different accounts.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+multiple+accounts

Comment: @phd thanks a lot for a hint, looks like the first link may help. Will devote more time to it later.